# Obtener variables de una fila y ponerlos en variables php

Tags: php, mysqli

Al obtener el valor de la fila que esta ubicado el usuario, quiero que almacene en la variable $_SESSION los demas campos puestos, como el email.

Aqui el codigo:

```
<?php

$usuario = $_POST['username'];
$clave = $_POST['password'];
//conexion

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "darkredc");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$usuario' and pass='$clave'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($filas == 1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = 'true';
    $_SESSION['user'] = $usuario;
    header("location: panel.php");
} else {
    echo "ERROR EN LA AUTENTIFICACION";
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: podrías ser mas claro por favor de lo que intentas obtener

Comment: lo que quieres es que cuando haces tu consulta, obtengas solo el id y el email pero de un solo usuario?

Comment: Por lo que veo, aquí no necesitas obtener las columnas realmente, sino verificar que el usuario existe nada más. La obtención de las columnas no es de ninguna utilidad para este caso, porque luego no las usas para nada... Es más yo escribiría la consulta así: `SELECT COUNT(*) filas FROM users WHERE ... `. Ah, y ten cuidado con la tabla `users`, que a veces se confunde con la tabla de usuarios del sistema de base de datos mismo, lo cual puede ser un riesgo. De todos modos, lo más grave es que tu código es vulnerable a la **Inyección SQL**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me permito indicar algunas cosas con respecto a tu código:

- Según la lógica del mismo, no pareces necesitar las columnas realmente, sino **verificar que el usuario existe**. La obtención de las columnas no es de ninguna utilidad para este caso, porque luego no las usas para nada...
- Si quieres hacer una verificación para luego redirigir a otra página, lo mejor sería hacer un conteo de filas.
- Puede que tu tabla `users` se confunda con una posible tabla `users` del sistema. Hace poco vi una pregunta que fallaba por ese motivo. Por eso no es recomendable llamar nuestras tablas con nombres que podrían terminar confundiéndose con posibles tablas del sistema. Para evitar eso, en este caso he encerrado el nombre de la tabla con comillas de identificación. Conviene que lo hagas siempre, si decides quedarte con ese nombre de tabla.
- Pero, lo más grave es que tu código es su vulnerabilidad de cara a la Inyección SQL.
- Otro error era que cerrabas los recursos después de la redirección. No tendría sentido, porque estarías en otra página y no dentro del ámbito del presente script. El cierre de recursos debe por tanto ser trasladado.

Te propongo esta solución, tomando en cuenta todo lo dicho más arriba.

```
$usuario = $_POST['username'];
$clave = $_POST['password'];

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "darkredc");
$consulta = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE user=? and pass=?";

$filas=0;
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $consulta)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $usuario, $clave);

    /* ejecutar la consulta */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* almacenar el resultado */
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $filas=mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

    /* cerrar la sentencia y la conexion*/
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}

if ($filas == 1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = 'true';
    $_SESSION['user'] = $usuario;
    header("location: panel.php");
} else {
    echo "ERROR EN LA AUTENTIFICACION";
}
```

---

Si quieres obtener valores de ciertas columnas, puedes hacerlo como se indica en el código de más abajo.

He asumido que tienes una columna llamada `id` y otra llamada `email` en tu tabla. Si no se llama así, **debes poner el nombre real de dichas columnas en el `SELECT`**.

No he puesto en esta segunda parte del código tu redirección `header("location: panel.php");`, porque este código muestra salida por pantalla. Y cuando usas `header`, no puede salir nada por pantalla antes de él.

Si necesitas las variables para usarlas en la redirección, debes quitar el `printf("%s %s\n", $id, $email);`, y puedes hacer una llamada así: `$stmt->fetch();` en vez del `while`. Entonces podrás usar las variables `$id` y `$email` en la redirección.

```
$usuario = $_POST['username'];
$clave = $_POST['password'];

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "darkredc");
$consulta = "SELECT id, email FROM `users` WHERE user=? and pass=?";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $consulta)) {    

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $usuario, $clave);

    /* ejecutar la consulta */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* mapear resultados a variables: dos columnas en el SELECT, dos variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$id, $email);
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $id, $email);
    }

    /* cerrar la sentencia y la conexion*/
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}
```

Comment: como aria para obtener el email? y el id que esta en la tabla?.

Comment: @CrisGO ahora edito y te muestro cómo hacerlo.

Comment: @CrisGO respuesta editada, indicando en la parte final cómo mostrar datos obtenidos en la consulta.